# Ripping off HTML tags and considering line breaks in a textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for my own web page and I have several textareas in it. Is there any way that I can prevent HTML tags to be stored in the database? Is there any utility that takes the text out clean?

Also, I do want to display line breaks, so when anyone types anything in the textarea and presses enter, it should produce a line break when displayed later. Should I store the `<br>` in the database?

I don't know if this can be done with CodeIgniter or any php function or javascript and/or jQuery has to be used, and how to do it.

Comment: You've HTML tags within textarea elements?

Comment: No, just the text you're going to input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [**`strip_tags`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for this... with an allowable tag `<br>` selected.

```
$text = strip_tags($htmltext,'<br>');// <br> is an allowed tag , others will be stripped off..
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would I generate `<br>` tags when a line break is entered?

Comment: Yeah you can do that using `nl2br()` , See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the php function strip tags: http://www.php.net/strip_tags